# pandas groupby with many categories and sort them by value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following data

| country | goodCode | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CN | 27000400 | 12 000 000 |
| KZ | 15000000 | 23 000 000 |
| ... | ... | ... |

overall there are over 150 different countries and over 12000 different goods (i.e. distinct goodCode)

How I can generate the following table :

| country | goodCode | Totalvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CN | 27000400 | 400 000 000 |
|  | 15000000 | 100 000 000 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| KZ | 15000000 | 244 000 000 |
|  | 27000400 | 130 000 000 |

Basically I want to group entire dataset by country and then by goodCode and then display it as for each country top good (i.e. goodCode) and total sum of this good.

When i applied `df.groupby(["country" ,"goodCode"]).sum().reset_index()` i had the following table

| country | goodCode | Totalvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CN | 27000400 | 400 000 000 |
| CN | 15000000 | 100 000 000 |
| CN | 45000000 | 700 000 000 |
| CN | 65000000 | 1 700 000 000 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| KZ | 15000000 | 244 000 000 |
| KZ | 27000400 | 130 000 000 |
| KZ | 37000400 | 530 000 000 |

It is 1. unsorted 2. Country name in each row.

When I applied `sort_values(by=["Totalvalue"], ascending = False)`
The DataFrame messed up. Countries mixed but sorted by value. It was something like:

| country | goodCode | Totalvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CN | 27000400 | 1 700 000 000 |
| KZ | 15000000 | 700 000 000 |
| AN | 45000000 | 200 000 000 |
| CN | 65000000 | 100 000 000 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| CA | 15000000 | 50 000 000 |
| AE | 27000400 | 25 000 000 |
| KZ | 37000400 | 20 000 000 |

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = (df.groupby(['country', 'goodCode'], as_index=False).sum()
         .sort_values(['country', 'Totalvalue'], ascending=[True, False]))
```

For example:

```
>>> df
  country  goodCode  Totalvalue
0      CN  27000400  1700000000
1      KZ  15000000   700000000
2      AN  45000000   200000000
3      CN  65000000   100000000
4      CA  15000000    50000000
5      AE  27000400    25000000
6      KZ  37000400    20000000

>>> df.sort_values(['country', 'Totalvalue'], ascending=[True, False])
  country  goodCode  Totalvalue
5      AE  27000400    25000000
2      AN  45000000   200000000
4      CA  15000000    50000000
0      CN  27000400  1700000000
3      CN  65000000   100000000
1      KZ  15000000   700000000
6      KZ  37000400    20000000
```